# How to share saved data from 2 different input fields

Tags: entities

This is hard to explain...but i will try.

I want users to be able to input their age in 2 different ways:

1. Date of birth field (this will display age with computed field)
2. Age with drop down integer (age from 18-99)

I want the age to be displayed on the same field in the User View Display.

Please ask for clarification if not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to compute age from *date field*:

```
    //compute age
    $bdayunix = strtotime($data->node_data_field_role_field_birthdate_value);
    $nowunix = time();
    $unixage = $nowunix - $bdayunix;
    $age = floor($unixage/ (365 * 24 * 60 * 60));

    print $age;
```

I hope these links will also help you solving your problem:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/149237
- http://www.kadimi.com/en/age-from-date-of-birth-in-drupal-7

Comment: Computed field works fine. I want the user to have 2 choices, age drop down with numbers 18-99 OR Date of birth. I want the data to be displayed  on the user profile.

Comment: You want user to have choice either he can enter date of birth or select his/her age. You actually doesn't want to save date, you just need the age, am I right??

Comment: Yes, I want the user to have the choice, but the results will be displayed in a single field on the user display, so 2 possible inputs, and one shared data display as age

Comment: I think, you just need a numeric select list age field in your user profile form, and then alter the form.
In alter, you can add the date field for birthday, so that user can select the birthday. At the submission of form, you can use the age from birthday using code above, and supply it to your age field.